# How to run unit test in python with Github and Jenkins?

Tags: unit-testing, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run unit test with Github and Jenkins, my target is:

- **[Done]** Build a Jenkins server and link to Github
- When a new pull request (PR) is created, or new push in the pull request, GitHub should send message to Jenkins server and run unit test.
- Jenkins server should return the logging information to GitHub, which can tell the developer what's wrong in the unit test.

The first target is done at present. I build a freestyle job in Jenkins server and link it to GitHub project. **However**, the tutorial is quiet simple and cannot satisfy my above requirements.

Split my second and third targets into different steps:

- How to run unit test only when new PR is created or new commit is pushed into the PR?
- How to judge the results of unit test (Success/Fail)? What should I do in Jenkins server?
- How to return the logging to Github?
- I haven't tried pipeline, should I use pipeline rather than freestyle job to implement my targets?

Answer (score 3):

For running tests for Pull Requests in GitHub there is a [GitHub Pull Request Builder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/) Jenkins plugin that does exactly what you want. It can also be configured to create a status check back in GitHub, so you can see from the PR if the job passed / failed.

There is also the [GitHub Pipeline plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin) but I personally don't have experience with that one.

Test results - depends on what the format of the results is. The general rule is that Jenkins by itself can't do almost nothing and you need to install a plugin to do what you want. For example for JUnit files, there is [JUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin) plugin that can publish the results and can create trend graphs in the job view.

Logging to GitHub - depends on what you mean by that. If the simple status check (OK / not OK + link to the jenkins build) is enough, this can the mentioned GHPRB plugin do for you. If you want to add something more, you can check the GH pipeline plugin or, what I personally used for simple messages back to GH, post the comment via the GitHub API.

Pipeline vs freestyle job - from my experience, nowadays people tend to use the pipeline more and it seems to be a preferred way to create new jobs, but there is nothing wrong with using freestyle job IMO.

Comment: Thanks~ I follow the document in Github Pull Request Builder and it works